# Specflow and HttpSelfHostServer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, mstest, specflow

I've created a self-hosted implementation of ASP.NET Web API and want this to run in SpecFlow tests.

So in my Specs i have a step firing up the selfhostserver as such:

```
var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:9000");    
var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);

 _apiApplication.Start(); //IoC, route-configs etc.

server.OpenAsync().Wait();

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = httpClient.GetAsync(fetchUrl).Result;
```

Exception that occur on the GetAsync-call:

```
Exception : System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. 
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. 
---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. 
---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection
```

The test run seem to prevent any call to the self-hosted API before the Specs are finished. When debugging, I can do a call to the url - but it hangs until the test run is complete. On completion, it gives a nice response.

I've also created a console-app which runs this code perfectly, and gives expected results.

Anyone with a SpecFlow test suite that does testing by HttpSelfHostServer, or any idea how to get a self-hosted WebApi working within a SpecFlow suite?

Comment: When are you firing this up? Is it inside a Given binding?

Comment: @Alski , I've tried putting it several SpecFlow segments. In a BeforeScenario, In a Given-step followed by a call using HttpClient, or just mushing it all in a single When. Same effect in all cases :/

I seem to get the same effect in a MSTest run as well, so might not be just SpecFlow.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do this for WCF services instead of web applications but in theory it should be the same.

One BIG problem is the freeing up of ports on the server, so as a result I allocate different ports for each run, with the following

```
private static int FreeTcpPort()
    {
        var l = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 0);
        l.Start();
        int port = ((IPEndPoint)l.LocalEndpoint).Port;
        l.Stop();
        return port;
    }


    [Given(@"a WCF Endpoint")]
    public void GivenAWCFEndpoint()
    {
        //The client 
        RemoteServerController.DefaultPort = FreeTcpPort();

        //The server
        var wcfListener = new ListenerServiceWCF
            {
                BindingMode = BindingMode.TCP,
                Uri = new Uri(string.Format("net.tcp://localhost:{0}",
                     RemoteServerController.DefaultPort))
            };
        //The wrapped host is quite a bit of generic code in our common libraries
        WrappedHostServices.Add(wcfListener);
        WrappedHostServices.Start();
    }
```

Even then I still get the occaisonal test fail, so if you can reduce the amount of infrastructure to run your code then I recommend running most of your tests without it and just a couple to ensure that it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've been watching this question since it was asked as we have been having exactly the same issue.

For the moment we are invoking IIS express to host our WebAPI services, starting them at the beginning of the specFlow run and disposing of them at the end, using the IIS Automation nuget package https://github.com/ElemarJR/IISExpress.Automation

We are also having problems with MS Test runner, but using ReSharper, they seem to all run correctly at present.

If anyone else has anything to contribute, Id also be very interested

Comment: Hi @Kerplosh. For us the problem was due to a global filter we registered. In the filter, we tried to access the HttpContext.Current, which throws a NullReferenceException in SelfHosted mode. Do check any custom attributes and filters for HttpContext.Current and add support for there to be no HttpContext as well. Could be the source of your problem as well.

Comment: @John Thanks for your response. We have some other interesting challenges to overcome - but will keep an eye out for references to HttpContext.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you forgot a Wait() statement on ReadAsync(). Try the below:

```
    var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:9000");    
    var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);

     _apiApplication.Start(); //IoC, route-configs etc.

    server.OpenAsync().Wait();

    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var requestTask = httpClient.GetAsync(fetchUrl);
    requestTask.Wait();
    var response = requestTask.Result;
```

That should keep your code from exiting immediately, which is probably why you're getting the exception.